# Counting two columns on the same query

Tags: mysql

Having this table

```
executing     failed
0              1
1              1
```

I want to get on a single query how much are executing and failed.

I know I can make them in separated querys:

```
SELECT count(*) executing FROM mytable where executing=1;
SELECT count(*) failed FROM mytable  where failed=1;
```

How how can I get the following output with a single query?

```
executing     failed
1              2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the columns contain only `0` and `1` just sum them up:

```
SELECT SUM(executing) executing, SUM(failed) failed FROM mytable
```

EDIT: You need `SUM` and not `COUNT` as others say because while it's true that `COUNT` does not count `NULL` values, it does in fact count the integer value `0` so it will give the wrong result in your case

Comment: That is entirely true in that case but that can be fixed with a case statement, so count(case) is a more general approach

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(executing), count(failed) from mytable
```

works always because count(col) does not count null entries in columns. So you dont need sum and you can always count on multiples columns with

```
 count(col)
```

regardless of the column datatype